# I'm running windows 10 and need Internet Explorer 5.5 or 6.0 to see images

Tags: windows-explorer, internet

I got a disc from my doctor that states that I need IE 5.5 or 6.0 to run it. I need to be able to see what is going on with the disc and I have tried several things that I've seen in here and even tried to download a virtual machine and nothing is working. help please.

Comment: It is not possible to run IE 5.5 or IE 6.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I also cannot imagine something that worked with either of those version but will not work with IE11.

Comment: It is very typical to get erroneous error messages like this from obsolete software that doesn’t understand that there are newer versions of IE available. The default is to complain that you aren’t running the correct version, only because it doesn’t recognize the version you have. You’re asking the wrong question. Give us detailed information about what you are doing and seeing so we can actually tel you how to fix the problem. IE5 or 6 is out of the question.

Comment: IE7 was released in 2006. Tel your doctor to update his crap...

Comment: See this....https://www.raymond.cc/blog/install-every-single-internet-explorer-versions-on-your-computer/

Comment: I wonder if the doctor is still running his medical practise on a bot-infested XP machine... That would be *great* for patient privacy... & probably a good case for suing him :/

Answer (score 3):

The warning you have got may be a false problem. Browse the disk with File Explorer and see the contents.
Then try to determine what is forcing the search for Internet Explorer.

I think that your disk has an autorun.inf that starts an 'index.htm' tailored for Internet Explorer 5 or 6.

Try to open this index.htm with your current browser, or Microsoft Edge, an see what happens.

As an expensive (extra time and resources) solution, install a virtual machine with Windows XP...